# Spinning wheel in React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm creating a lottery app with React.js. There is a spinning wheel in SVG format.
You can spin a wheel and it smoothly stops at a given position (my app makes it random position).

[image: The spinning wheel]

I made the wheel a React.js component that you use like this:

```
<Wheel items={items} fullSpins={5} angle={0} />
```

Parameters are:

- [array] **items**
  Parts of the wheel defining their color, proportion etc.
- [int] **fullSpins**
  How many spins the wheel makes before stopping at the requested **angle**. This is for visual appeal and more thrill.
- [float: 0..360] **angle**
  The angle in degrees at which the wheel is about to be stopped.

I'd like any other component to be able to spin the wheel, so I assume that the React.js-like way to do it would be to do it on a property change. When `angle` is changed, I would set the `transform: rotate(Xdeg)`, where X is `current angle + fullSpins * 360 + angle`. With `transition-property: transform` it spins smoothly.

I'm not sure how to handle it React way. Normally I would consider a method that would just be passed to the wheel, but spinning is internal behavior of the wheel itself. Perfectly, it would just spin on `angle` property update. However, what if I want to spin it to the same position, like when two times in row it was decided to stop it at the angle 90.0 degrees?

Should I use `componentWillReceiveProps()`? If so, how to know if the new spin was actually requested when the previous angle was the same?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `componentDidUpdate()` to check if props has changed and then call your spin function accordingly.

Something like this:

```
class Wheel extends Component {

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        if(prevProps.angle !== this.props.angle) this.spinFunction()
    }

    spinFunction(){
        // update transform: rotate(Xdeg) etc here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I mentioned twice that the angle can stay the same.

Comment: Ok well this is the react way of doing. You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` in a similar way but at the end of the day, you need to tell your component to call your spin function. So if the angle can potentially stay the same, maybe you can do a check to see if `this.props.items` has changed. Alternatively you could pass through an ID of sorts on each wheel component and check if that has changed.

Comment: That was also my thought to pass either some ID or just a spinning increment. If that's the way React.js developers do things, I'll do it.

Comment: @RoboRobok : Do you have any open source code of what you have developed? I am working on the same spinning wheel, but I was expecting some reference so if you could provide, let me know.